# Is there a command line C++ to PDF converter with syntax highlighting?

Tags: c++, pdf, documentation, syntax-highlighting

I need to supply "Source code documents w/ Line numbers" which is essentially just a PDF of the source code with syntax highlighting and Line numbers.  Is there any existing command line tools for windows that I could call from a script as a "build release version" script?

Right now I'm doing it manually using VC++, which isn't even the dev enviroment the code is for a TI processor, and a PDF printer driver, which has a pop up for each file I print.

Comment: I am confused, why would you want to print your entire source?

Comment: Customer requirement.  "Source code document including line numbers."  I just want something to automatically generate the files. (Something I can script.)

Comment: Seems like the answers are not working for you, isn't it?

Answer (score 28):

Two syntax highlighters I use are `enscript` and `source-highlight`.

The first can output to PostScript (that you can convert to PDF using ps2pdf), the second produces output in HTML, LaTeX and other formats.

Both should be available via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

**EDIT:** On my system the following command will print all the cpp files in the current subtree.

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs enscript -Ecpp -fCourier8
```

While the following will produce a `code.pdf` file with the same content

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs enscript -Ecpp -fCourier8 -o - | ps2pdf - code.pdf
```

PS: and give the `--color=1` for color output and `-C` for line numbers.

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs enscript --color=1 -C -Ecpp -fCourier8 -o - | ps2pdf - code.pdf
```

Comment: `enscript` uses default media size A4. If you want to use letter size, add `-M Letter` to the `enscript` options.

Answer (score 3):

I use this. It generates .ps. Then you can run ps2pdf.

```
# Copyright 2004 Rutger E.W. van Beusekom.
# Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
# accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
# http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

outfile=$1
shift

a2ps -1 --highlight=normal --pretty-print=cxx --line-numbers=1 -M a4 -L80 -g \
-o $outfile $* --prologue=color --right-title=%p. --left-title \
--left-footer --right-footer --header --medium=a4
```

You could also use Doxygen with source browsing enabled.
There is also htmlize.el by Hrvoje Niksic for emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I tested several alternatives and **enscript** had the best result to print the source code.
So, I wrote this bash script (needs *bash*, *enscript*, *ps2pdf*, *pdfjam*) a few minutes ago to collect all sources in the current directory:

usage example: ./script.sh *.h *.c

```
#!/bin/bash
test "x$1" == "x" && echo "usage: $0 <sourcefiles>" && exit 0

for f in "$@" ; do enscript $f -o $f.ps -E -C ; done

for f in *.ps ; do echo ps2pdf $f ; ps2pdf $f && rm $f ; done

rm OUTPUT.pdf 2>/dev/null
pdfjam *.pdf && mv *pdfjam.pdf OUTPUT.pdf

echo
echo DONE:
echo OUTPUT.pdf
```

WARNING: This script is a bad hack and will delete *.ps and OUTPUT.pdf in the current directory.
It assumes all input files are in the current directory.