# Convert all files of a specified extension within a directory to pdf, recursively for all sub-directories

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs, enscript

I'm using the following code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649452/1824033)) to convert all CPP files in the current directory to a file named code.pdf and it works well:

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - | ps2pdf - code.pdf
```

I would like to improve this script to:

1. Make it a .sh file that can take an argument specifying the
   extension instead of having it hardcoded to CPP;
2. Have it run recursively, visiting all subdirectories of the current directory;
3. For each subdirectory encountered, convert all files of the specified extension to a single PDF that is named *$NameOfDirectory$.PDF* and is placed in that subdirectory;

Comment: `find` will retrieve all files in all sub-directories that end with the extension (`cpp` in your example). If this is what you wanted, your recursive bullet makes no sense. I you wanted all files in the current directory, there is no reason to use find.

Comment: The line I'm using is the base I'm working from and was taken from another answer on StackOverflow (see link). My bullet points are the improvements I want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if I understand it correctly, this requirement:

> For each subdirectory encountered, convert all files of the specified extension to a single PDF that is named $NameOfDirectory$.PDF

is unwise. If that means, say, `a/b/c/*.cpp` gets enscripted to `./c.pdf`, then you're screwed if you also have `a/d/x/c/*.cpp`, since both directories' contents map to the same PDF. It also means that `*.cpp` (i.e. CPP files in the *current* dir) gets enscripted to a file named `./..pdf`.

Something like this, which names the PDF according to the desired extension and places it in each subdirectory alongside its source files, doesn't have those problems:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# USAGE: ext2pdf [<ext> [<root_dir>]]
# DEFAULTS: <ext> = cpp
#           <root_dir> = .
ext="${1:-cpp}"
rootdir="${2:-.}"

shopt -s nullglob

find "$rootdir" -type d | while read d; do

  # With "nullglob", this loop only runs if any $d/*.$ext files exist
  for f in "$d"/*.${ext}; do

    out="$d/$ext".pdf
    # NOTE: Uncomment the following line instead if you want to risk name collisions
    #out="${rootdir}/$(basename "$d")".pdf

    enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - "$d"/*.${ext} | ps2pdf - "$out"

    break   # We only want this to run once

  done

done
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify that I WANT the PDF next to the source files so there's one PDF per directory containing CPP files. I'm testing your approach and will comment back.

Comment: It doesn't work. I printf-debugged and it seems to be going thru all directories, but the for loop doesn't work (for f in "$d"/*.${e}; do). I am positive that there are CPP files within those sub-directories.

Comment: @binarez Whoops, sorry. I was renaming `$e` to `$ext` for clarity, but didn't change every instance. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

First, if I understand correctly, what you are using is in fact wrong - `find` will retrieve the files from all sub-directories. To work recursively, only getting files from the current directory (I named it `do.bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash

ext=$1
if ls *.$ext &> /dev/null; then
    enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - *.$ext | ps2pdf - $(basename $(pwd)).pdf
fi
for subdir in */; do
    if [ "$subdir" == "*/" ]; then break; fi
    cd $subdir
    /path/to/do.bash $ext
    cd ../
done
```

The checks are to make sure a file with the extension or a sub directory actually exist. This scripts operates on the current directory, and calls itself recursively - if you do not want a full path, put it in your PATH listings, though a full path is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'll go with the solution that doesn't require the script to be in the user's path, for simplicity of usage.