# Files to PDF with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, pdf

Hi any idea how this could work?
I would like to go through different directories that I have stored in an array, each of these directories should be searched for files with the extension (.c, .cpp, .txt) and the content of the files should be printed in a pdf, so that at the end I I only have one .pdf with all the content.  the directory structure looks like this

```
$directories=("kl01-001" "kl01-002" "kl01-003" "kl01-004" "kl01-005")    
/homedir/$directories/solution/
```

The files I'm looking for are in the solutions directory.

i have found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632016/convert-all-files-of-a-specified-extension-within-a-directory-to-pdf-recursivel)

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - | ps2pdf - code.pdf
```

works fine for one directory, but logically, whenever I try to put it in a loop, the out file is overwritten with the contents of the last directory in the array.

found this at the same post and i think that could be the solution, but my programming skills are too bad to loop this like I need.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# USAGE: ext2pdf [<ext> [<root_dir>]]
# DEFAULTS: <ext> = cpp
#           <root_dir> = .
ext="${1:-cpp}"
rootdir="${2:-.}"

shopt -s nullglob

find "$rootdir" -type d | while read d; do

  # With "nullglob", this loop only runs if any $d/*.$ext files exist
  for f in "$d"/*.${ext}; do

    out="$d/$ext".pdf
    # NOTE: Uncomment the following line instead if you want to risk name collisions
    #out="${rootdir}/$(basename "$d")".pdf

    enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - "$d"/*.${ext} | ps2pdf - "$out"

    break   # We only want this to run once

  done

done
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` accepts a list of paths, so you can simply modify your first attempt to list the directories in which you want to select cpp files :

```
find "/homedir/kl01-00{1,2,3,4,5}/solution" -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - | ps2pdf - code.pdf
```

In this command I use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to expand `"/homedir/kl01-00{1,2,3,4,5}/solution"` into 5 words which correspond to the 5 directories named in your array.

Comment: hi thanks, didn't know this.
is it possible to find with something like this?

find "/homedirs/${directories[@]}/solution/"

or should I just run through my array again beforehand and add the solution directory to it?

Comment: @ZoniK Unless you're set on using an array, I think the best would be to use brace expansion. I've updated my answer to use it. Assuming all your directories don't fit the "kl01-00X" format you can add additionnal expansions after (e.g. `find "/homedir/kl01-00{1,2,3,4,5}/solution" "/homedir/kl02-00{1,2,3}/solution" "/homedir/kl03-00{3,4,5}/solution"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we want to call ps2pdf only once.   I see two different approaches already in this thread:

1. Your approach - add directories and file types one at a time.
2. Aaron's approach - add everything all at once

Let's work with Aaron's approach first (this is very straight forward).  Just invoke find to get all the files you need in one shot.  You can handle multiple extensions with the `-o` (or "or") flag.  And as Aaron pointed out, you can use `find` to search multiple subdirectories at once:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -name *.cpp -o -name *.txt -o name *.c | xargs -0 enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - | ps2pdf - code.pdf
```

Let's now look at your approach.

With your approach, you just need to save the files to a file (by appending) and then invoke `enscript` and `ps2pdf`.

Here's your program again, but all it's going to do is create list_o_files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# USAGE: ext2pdf [<ext> [<root_dir>]]
# DEFAULTS: <ext> = cpp
#           <root_dir> = .
ext="${1:-cpp}"
rootdir="${2:-.}"

shopt -s nullglob

find "$rootdir" -type d -name "$ext" >> list_o_files
```

And here's another command to take list_o_files and produce the required output:

```
enscript -Ecpp -MLetter -fCourier8 -o - $(<list_o_files) | ps2pdf -
```

Comment: There is a caveat - since list_o_files is given a relative path (that is, it's created in the current directory) if you move around you will create multiple files call list_o_files.  You might just want to give it an absolute name, like `~/list_o_files`.